# How to approach attendance reporting through Excel, then to Power BI?

Tags: excel, vba, powerbi

I need to create an attendance reporting tool in Power BI based off an Excel visual that is marked by color coded cells whether someone is on leave, teleworking, or onsite. What is the best way to go about this?

Calendar example

[image: 1]

Calendar legend

[image: 2]

It is important to note that this Excel sheet is online and can be updated by the user just by copying the color that corresponds to their status to their name/day block. I need Power BI to recognize these real time changes.

So far I've split up the information into tables like a database schema that connect to this main table.

schemaish

[image: 3]

I want to know if there's a good way to be able to read the color coded cells from a previous sheet and rewrite them as a value in the table that I've provided above.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39347073/read-excel-cell-colour-into-power-bi

Comment: Please, [don't post a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) use this [VBA code](https://davetallett26.github.io/excel-markdown.html) to create a Markdown table or use this [website](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to create a Markdown table.

Comment: I thought it was volatile. Well live and learn. Deleting comment

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend that the calendar be updated from colour to data. Colour is not data, colour is not accessible (color blindness, especially shades of red). Have folks enter "data" into the cells like:

| Description | Key |
| --- | --- |
| Onsite | O |
| Recurring Telework Day | R |
| Telework Day - Ad-hoc | X |
| Telework Day - Max Telework Day | M |
| Annual Leave | AL |
| Sick Leave | SL |

This will also be far easier for folks to enter and update via mobile devices.  Set-up conditional formatting if you like to colour code based on these values, but ultimately, it's the data in the cells and not the formatting.

As for the data model, I would recommend a table structure similar to:

| Group ID | Employee ID | Date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 2024-01-01 | O |
| 2 | 1 | 2024-01-02 | SL |